# Floating left/right image not responsive

Tags: html, css

I have a floating left/right ad, the width is working fine as responsive but I cannot figure out the height.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<div id="leftads" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto; text-align:left; position:fixed; z-index:1001; bottom:1%;left:1%;">
  <div>
    <a href="#" id="adclose" style="color:#333333;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;text-shadow:black 0.1em 0.1em 0.1em;padding-top:3px;padding-right:0px">
      <a href="" onclick="document.getElementById('leftads').style.display = 'none'; return false">[x] close ad</a>
    </a>
  </div>
  <!--Start Left Ad -->
  ad code
  <!--End of Left Ad -->
</div>
<div id="rightads" style="max-width: 100%; height: auto; text-align:right; display:scroll;position:fixed; z-index:1001; bottom:1%;right:1%;">
  <div>
    <a href="#" id="adclose" style="color:#333333;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold;text-shadow:black 0.1em 0.1em 0.1em;padding-top:3px;padding-left:0px">
      <a href="" onclick="document.getElementById('rightads').style.display = 'none'; return false">[x] close ad</a>
    </a>
  </div>
  <!--Start Right Ad-->
  ad code
  <!--End of Right Ad -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the down vote for nothing

Comment: You set the height to auto. Where do you want to use the height?

Comment: a height:auto; never works, except you have a specific value set on the parent element. If you want that it has the full height of parent element without setting the height, you can either use flexbox (IE10+) or use position: absolute; top:0;bottom:0; but don't forget that it's taken then out of the flow with the absolute positioning. So if there's only absolute items in a div, it has no height anymore..

Comment: does setting a height value work?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the height if you want to change it.

```
  <div style="height:150px">left</div>
  <div style="height:150px">right</div>
```